# The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading in the Godaddy

Tags: php, wordpress, visual-composer, wp-admin

This page isn’t working `rvold.com/rvold_live` - didn’t send any data. Here is what I got in response: `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`.

On editing or Updating my homepage in `wp-admin`, the page giving me Errors, when I am clicking on update button.

I have increased:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
php_value post_max_size 64M
php_value max_execution_time 800
php_value max_input_time 800
```

in `php.ini` and `.htaccess` file, too, but not helped.

The site hosted in the Godaddy server.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution. The only difference between my bluehost (where it worked) and Godaddy (where the issues was persistent) is the php version. My Godaddy was set at php 5. I changed that to 7 and so far so good.